# Adding variables into an ajax header parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So this seemed like a simple task but spent already over an hour on this. I just want to pass a variable into the ajax header parameter. For some reason this is causing alot of problems. Im getting 500 errors returning from our server but if I type in the variable manually everything magically works. Not quite sure if theres a basic rule im not understanding but something isn't right. Anyone have any idea?

Below is my code and the viariable I need to pass is the `headertype`.

```
saveIncident: function () {
    if (!confirm('Save?')) return

    var requestType = '' != '' ? 'PUT' : 'POST';
    var POST_Headers = '{"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"}';
    var PUT_Headers =  '{"Accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose","X-HTTP-Method':'MERGE","If-Match": item.__metadata.etag}';
    var headertype = (requestType != 'POST') ? POST_Headers : PUT_Headers;

    $.ajax({
        url: this.createIncidentUrl(requestType),
        type: requestType,
        processData: false,
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers: headertype,
        data: JSON.stringify(IncidentManager.collectFieldValues()),
        success: function (data) {
        if (requestType == 'POST')
            console.log(data.d);   
            }
        });
},
```

Comment: `var requestType = '' != '' ? 'PUT' : 'POST';` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `headers` value you're passing to `$.ajax` should be an object, not a string.

So you'll need to remove the single quotes here:

```
var POST_Headers = {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"};
var PUT_Headers =  {"Accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose","X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE","If-Match": item.__metadata.etag};
```

Comment: Im getting syntax errors: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,`  with `var PUT_Headers =  {"Accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose","X-HTTP-Method':'MERGE","If-Match": item.__metadata.etag};`

Comment: Nevermind got it var PUT_Headers =  {"Accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose","X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE","If-Match": "item.__metadata.etag"};

Comment: THank you very much for the info Wouter :)